# DearPyGui: Main window always on top

Tags: python, dearpygui

With dearpygui, I would like to have the main window (the one that contains all the other windows) to always be on top, even if it does not have focus.
Here is what I have so far :

```
from dearpygui.core import *
from dearpygui.simple import *


with window('MainWindow', width=500, height=500):
    add_button('Read screen')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with this solution for now. I'll edit my answer if it gets supported by the library. This is a feature in their roadmap for now ([see this issue](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/185)).

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

import win32con
import win32gui
from dearpygui.core import *
from dearpygui.simple import *


with window('MainWindow', width=500, height=500):
    add_button('Read screen')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # you have to make a new process for this in order to be able
    # to call win32gui.FindWindow on your displayed window
    p = Process(target=start_dearpygui) 
    p.start()

    # sleep for a while to let your window get displayed
    sleep(4)

    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow('DearPyGui', None)
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, 300, 200, 0)
```